# How does selected dropdown value get saved from View Component to main model?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web app. The question is HOW it works, not why it doesn't. I don't understand the mechanism and so don't want to see it fail from some "happy-fingers" coding accident in the future...

I have a main model that the controller expects on create:

```
public class ProductCategory : BaseClass
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

(`BaseClass` just has your typical record keeping fields).

I have a model for the view components; I need two, one for each dropdown, so you can easily imagine the other, with names modified to protect the innocent...:

Category:

```
public class CategoryList
{
    public CategoryList()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Categories")]
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The category view component:

```
public class CategoryDropdownViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public CategoryDropdownViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var items = await GetCategoriesAsync();
        var TheView = "Default";
        var list = new CategoryList();

        if (items.Count == 0)
        {
            TheView = "CategoryMaintenanceLink";
        }
        else
        {
            items.Insert(0, new Category() { Id = 0, Name = "-- Please select an option --" });
            list.Categories = items;
        }

        return View(TheView, list);
    }

    private Task<List<Category>> GetCategoriesAsync()
    {
        return _db.Category.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

And the default view for category (I store this and above in `~\Shared\Components\CategoryDropdown\`):

```
@model CoolestProjectNameEver.Models.CategoryList

<p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
</p>
```

So, in my controller, I kick off create:

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And in the `Create` view, amongst other things, I fire up the view components:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductDropdown")
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryDropdown")
        </div>
```

All works and the dropdown lists are filled. I can select options for both. Now the unknown part.

On to the `POST` method for `Create`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductCategory productCategory)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)        <--- breakpoint
            {
                _context.Add(productCategory);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return View(productCategory);
    }
```

The breakpoint will show the correct selected values for `CategoryId` and `ProductId`.

So the question is, did this work because of a name match in the VC model to main controller model, and it auto filled somehow?

**1** if my `ViewComponent` model had, say `SelectedValueId` instead of `CategoryId`, then it would fail because of a mismatch?

**2** How did the value from a *separate model* in an async `ViewComponent` get plugged into the main model on postback?

Comment: The edit to remove the parameter is incorrect as View Component documentation states all parameters (even if just used in Edit mode) must always be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact,if you change your `Create` view code to:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductDropdown")
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("CategoryDropdown")
    </div>
```

it will also successfully binding.

The model binding in asp.net core is matched according to the `name`. If the name matches, the corresponding attribute will be bound to the model.

In your ViewComponent, your code(`model => model.CategoryId`):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

will be given `name =CategoryId` in the generated html code
[image]

Then the name `CategoryId` is also in your `ProductCategory` model, if their names match, the binding will be successful.

Comment: I needed to add the parameter, via:  @await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductDropdown", new { productId = Model.ProductId }) so that in the Edit command, the proper item in the dropdown would be selected. Yes, it's not required on 'Create', as it's a new record. But documentation stated all parameters must be sent at all times.